# Preventing trackPageView call in GA from GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have many clients that are using Google Analytics (GA) via Google Tag Manager (GTM) on their website. My company provides AJAX pages for our client's site where we track user interaction using custom trackPageView calls. For regular GA code this was not a problem - we would set up the GA code in the static header, omitting the trackpageview call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq=_gaq||[];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-5620270-1']);
</script>
```

and then whenever the user interacts with something on the AJAX portion of the page (initial page load, clicking options etc) we call trackPageView with a virtual URL

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/someurl?param1=abc&param2=def']);
```

The problem we have with GTM is that we are getting double tracking - the initial trackPageView call coming from GTM, then the virtual URL call on the AJAX portion of the page - on initial page loads. We can't disable the virtual URL on initial page loads on our end. We need to be able to get GTM to send through all the GA code (setAccount, domain name etc) except for the trackPageView bit. Is there any way to do this in GTM?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but easy to implement solutions:

- pass a virtual url to the page call in GTM and set up a filter in your data views that excludes this url from the reports *or*
- place your GA code in a custom tag instead of using a code template and omit the trackPageView-Call

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this option is possible given your description, but virtual pageviews are not the best solution -- the total pageviews and related metrics are inflated and you cannot tell which segments are really engaging with the site more and which less.

Event tracking would be a smart way to do this. And with new GTM this is not difficult to setup at all. You could create all-new tracking (to the same account) and attach a string to your new tags, and then simply add include-only filter that will not allow any other requests.

Comment: We offer AJAX and non-AJAX solutions and we want the AJAX solution to track exactly as the non-AJAX solution does which is why we use the virtual pageviews. The AJAX portion of the page is practically the entire page (everything except for the global header/footer).